# Insufficient access error on record for a profile

Tags: custom-object, permissions, profile, owd

I have Read permission on a object for a profile. Also, OWD settings is Public Read/Write. Still the record is getting insufficient access for the relevant User.

Why am I getting this error? Why is the record not visible?

Comment: Is the page you're trying to see it through standard or a Custom Visualforce page? Could it be that the Profile doens't have access to the visualforce page?

Comment: Yes it is through a custom page and I have given access to it. Still the error shows

Comment: Check field level security as well for that profile. Also the current user will only see the records it owns.

Comment: also if there is a master detail relationship present you would need to ensure that the profile has access to both ends of that relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You should try giving access to the custom page as well as the controller.

Comment: This could be a comment until it is confirmed.